# json_decode giving error in php for webservice call

Tags: php, json, web-services

I am consuming a webservice in PHP , below is code sample

> ```
> >         if ( $datas=file_get_contents($url) ) return json_decode($datas);
> >         return Array('error' => "Can't open url");
> ```

I return the the value of above function call to js page. but I dont get the value of webservice call in js but always get error value. However if I open the $url in browser I get below data (valid json) :

> {"d":[ [ 5.305,428 ] ] }

Due to framework restriction i can use only json_decode() to return values back to my js page.
I also tried json_decode($datas,true); but still no help.

I also tried consuming same code in standalone php file :
I get this error : when I use json_decode($datas)

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice-demo\clientRestTest.php on
>   line 32

and below error if I use json_decode($datas,true);

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice-demo\clientRestTest.php on line 32 Array

Please let me know how to resolve the issue .

Answer (score 0):

Is there any special chars in $url? if there is, try urlencoding it first

file_get_contents(urlencode($url)); etc etc